# Bootstrap 3: form label position depending on master column

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, label, size

I'm designing a module in bootstrap, and I want to have the position of my label in a form depending on the width of the master column. Using the `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*`, etc the position (as a result of the size) depends on the screen width, not on the masters width. Is there a way to do that?

For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 control-label" for="MyId">Label</label>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <input id="MyId" name="MyName" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" class="form-control input-md" value=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Behaves nice on all screen sizes, but if I include this part in a box  it has not enough space for the label and thus it does not place the label above the input field.

Is there an other possibility than just: "change the `col-md-2` and the `col-md-8` both to `col-md-12`"? This, because than in a large box the label is not in front of the input field. I'm looking for an alternative where I can have the same code for the the form-group with different behavior in small and large boxes.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-md-offset-2`:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label " for="MyId">Label</label>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <input id="MyId" name="MyName" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" class="form-control input-md" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can align label text horisontally: `text-right` or `text-left` or `text-center`